# typescript.- how can I validate specific fields in child class using class validator and class transformer (Nestjs)

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I am trying to working with base calls in Nestjs with class-validator and class-transform

I have a base class as follows:

```
class BaseClass{
   @IsString()
   name:string;

   @IsNumber()
   num:number;
}
```

now I have a service that should get childDto

```
service....
async fun(child:childDTO){

  const dto = plainToClass(child)
  await validate(dto)// or via validate pipe
}
```

now I would like a dto  that includes only the "name" and validate in the controller or service

`class childDto extends BaseClass{}`

how can I make sure to take only "name" field
instead, create another dto with code duplication

and also to make sure the validation is working per specific DTO

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PickType

```
export class childDto extends PickType(BaseClass, ['name'] as const) {}
```

For more details visit [mapped-types#pick](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#pick)

Answer (score 0):

I think syntax planToClass err please check again 
example: `let users = plainToClass(User, userJson);`